# Is there a library which handles the parsing of BIND zone files in Python?

Tags: python, database, parsing, bind, python-2.4

This is related to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236859/any-python-libs-for-parsing-bind-config-files) about BIND, but in this case I'm trying to see if there's any easy way to parse various zone files into a dictionary, list, or some other manageable data structure, with the final goal being committing the data to a database.

I'm using BIND 8.4.7 and Python 2.4. I *may* be able to convince management to use a later Python version if needed, but the BIND version is non-negotiable at the moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236859/any-python-libs-for-parsing-bind-config-files

Comment: I mentioned that. That ?? was talking about *config* files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISTM, [easyzone](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/easyzone/) might meet your needs. It sits on top of dnspython, which would be an alternative API.

Comment: `easyzone` lacks support for some record type like PTR. It's fine if you just need to work with `CNAME`, `A` and `TXT` etc, but if you really want to support all DNS record types, read `easyzone`'s code and write your own using `dnspython`