# How to parse dhcpd.conf files with python and bicop?

Tags: python, parsing, dns, dhcp

I want to edit files (dhcpd.conf, dns files) with python. I was looking for any option and i found bicop library. I try to do:

```
from bicop import parse
parse("/home/tigov/dhcp/dhcpd.conf")
```

and i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bicop/config.py", line 83, in parse
    return _Parse(tokenizer, dictclass=dictclass)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/bicop/config.py", line 141, in _Parse
    raise ParseError, (input.infile, input.lineno, "Unexpected end of file")
bicop.config.ParseError: None[1]: Unexpected end of file
```

Any ideas what i have to do, or any "bicop how to"? Or maybe another library to do this? (iscpy library doesn't work well for me) Thanks for help and sorry, my english is weak.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the examples for bicop don't work.  Parse only accepts string input.  Try this:

```
from bicop import parse
parse(open("/home/tigov/dhcp/dhcpd.conf").read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236859/any-python-libs-for-parsing-bind-zone-files) is helpful here.  bicop does not appear to work for parsing more complex ISC config files, but [iscpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iscpy) seems to

```
# Here is the file that I'm parsing (which bicop won't parse)
#
# zone "example.com" IN {
#   type master;
#   file "/var/named/example.com";
#   allow-update { none; };
# };

>>> import iscpy
>>> iscpy.ParseISCString(open('./named.conf').read())
{'zone "example.com" IN': {'allow-update': {'none': True},
  'file': '"/var/named/example.com"',
  'type': 'master'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify ISC files in a nice fashion, preserving comments, adapting to existing formatting etc, the confctl utility might be a good choice: https://github.com/trasz/confctl/