# Parsing DNS text files with python

Tags: python, parsing, dns

I am an absolute and complete newbie to Python, having it installed on my computer only an hour ago.

I am starting in a carve-out project splitting up a quite complex DNS system and have a major need to parse the various named.conf and zone files on some 20+ BIND servers.

For starters I need to identify which DNS zones the differents servers considers themselves masters for.

My initial though is to use Python to read the named.conf text file, search for "type master;" and output the name of the zone in a text file or whatever.

**An excerpt of an example named.conf:**

```
zone "92.34.163.in-addr.arpa" in { 
type master; 
file "92.34.163.in-addr.arpa.db"; 
        update-policy {
        grant _nbc_update_channel_key_only_ wildcard * ANY;        };}; 

zone "aam.hal.hydro.com" in { 
type master;   
file "aam.hal.hydro.com.db"; 
        update-policy {
        grant _nbc_update_channel_key_only_ wildcard * ANY;        };};
```

**A desired output in a text file would be:**

```
master 10.10.10.in-addr.arpa    
master kodal.no
master smula.no
```

Any tip would be appreciated!

Comment: I think that if you tried writing some pseudocode for this first, then you will be able to solve this quite easily with python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any python libs for parsing Bind zone files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236859/any-python-libs-for-parsing-bind-zone-files)

Comment: I suggest you first read the *complete* Python tutorial which will answer most of your questions automagically :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`bicop`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bicop) to parse such files:

```
from bicop import parse
parse(open("/etc/bind/named.conf"))
```

Comment: I don't think bicop works correctly for config that looks like:

    zone "example.com" IN {
        type master;
    };
  
It complains that the required separator is missing.

Answer (score 0):

In your place I'd probably use a parser generator such as [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) to write a parser to extract the needed information from the various DNS configuration files.