# python parse bind configuration with nested curly braces

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm trying to automatically parse an existing bind configuration, consisting of multiple of these zone definitons:

```
zone "domain.com" {
        type slave;
        file "sec/domain.com";
        masters {
                11.22.33.44;
                55.66.77.88;
        };
        allow-transfer {
             "acl1";
             "acl2";
        };
};
```

note that the amount of elements in `masters` and in `allow-transfer` may differ. I tried my way around splitting this using `re.split()` and failed horribly due to the nested curly braces.

My goal is a dictionary for each of these entries.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any python libs for parsing Bind zone files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236859/any-python-libs-for-parsing-bind-zone-files)

Comment: this is no zone file, this is the bind configuration.

Comment: What is between each 'zone' definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, where 'st' is a string of all your zone definitions:

```
import re
zone_def = re.split('zone', st, re.DOTALL)
big_dict = {}
for zone in zone_def:
    if len(zone) > 0:
        zone_name = re.search('(".*?")', zone)
        sub_dicts = re.finditer('([\w]+) ({.*?})', zone, re.DOTALL)
        big_dict[zone_name.group(1)] = {}
        for sub_dict in sub_dicts:
            big_dict[zone_name.group(1)][sub_dict.group(1)] = sub_dict.group(2).replace(' ', '')
        sub_types = re.finditer('([\w]+) (.*?);', zone)
        for sub_type in sub_types:
            big_dict[zone_name.group(1)][sub_type.group(1)] = sub_type.group(2)
```

big_dict will then return a dictionary of zone definitions. Each zone definition will have the domain/url as its key. Every key/value in the zone definition is a string.

This is the output for the above example:

```
{'"domain.com"': {'transfer': '{\n"acl1";\n"acl2";\n}', 'masters': '{\n11.22.33.44;\n55.66.77.88;\n}', 'type': 'slave', 'file': '"sec/domain.com"'}}
```

And this is the output if you were to have a second identical zone, with key "sssss.com".

```
{'"sssss.com"': {'transfer': '{\n"acl1";\n"acl2";\n}', 'masters': '{\n11.22.33.44;\n55.66.77.88;\n}', 'type': 'slave', 'file': '"sec/domain.com"'},'"domain.com"': {'transfer': '{\n"acl1";\n"acl2";\n}', 'masters': '{\n11.22.33.44;\n55.66.77.88;\n}', 'type': 'slave', 'file': '"sec/domain.com"'}}
```

You will have to do some further stripping to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

A way is to (install and) use the regex module instead of the re module. The problem is that the re module is unable to deal with undefined level of nested brackets:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import regex
data = '''zone "domain.com" {
    type slave;
    file "sec/domain.com";
    masters {
        11.22.33.44; { toto { pouet } glups };
        55.66.77.88;
    };
    allow-transfer {
        "acl1";
        "acl2";
    };
};  '''

pattern = r'''(?V1xi)
(?:
    \G(?<!^)
  |
    zone \s (?<zone> "[^"]+" ) \s* {
) \s*
(?<key> \S+ ) \s+
(?<value> (?: ({ (?> [^{}]++ | (?4) )* }) | "[^"]+" | \w+ ) ; )
'''

matches = regex.finditer(pattern, data)

for m in matches:
    if m.group("zone"):
        print "\n" + m.group("zone")
    print m.group("key") + "\t" + m.group("value")
```

You can find more informations about this module by following this link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex